# How hadoop works inside docker container deployed in a cluster on cloud?

Tags: hadoop, docker, hdfs, containers

I am unable to wrap my head around how HDFS will work inside a container. Containers by design are meant to be isolated and HDFS is distributed. So if I have multiple containers with hadoop in each of them how they communicate and how data is stored.

Comment: Your assumption that containers are meant to be isolated is wrong. Docker provides ways to manage virtual networks for containers, export ports, etc. Containers are isolated by default from security reasons but that doesn't mean that they meant to be kept that way

Comment: In real sense yes they are not truly isolated.

Comment: The Java runtime for the Hadoop processes are what's isolated. The datanode and namenode volumes+ports need to be exposed to the host. Majority of people argue that stateful systems like filesystems and database should not be in containers